# How to find matches in descriptors using L2 norm (python)?

Tags: python, computer-vision

I need some clarification in order to understand how image matching work. Basically, I calculated keypoints (keypoints1, keypoints2) of img1 and img2. After I calculated descriptors (desc1, desc2). After that I used cdist function from scipy library to calculate the L2 norm of those descriptors. Now I do not understand how to find the matches using distances calculated. I don't understand how to find appropriate indexes that match. If possible can you show in python vector examples? (Like desc1 = [[1,2],[3,4]] and desc2 = [[5,6],[0.9, 2.1]]. Clearly here desc1[0] and desc2[1] has the minimum distance.)

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something along those lines?

```
scores=scipy.spatial.distance.cdist(desc1,desc2)

matches=scores.argsort(1)
```

In the snippet above,`scores[i,j]` contains the matching score between `desc1[i]` and `desc2[j]`, and

```
matches[i]=[index_1, ..., index_k]
```

is such that `desc2[index_1]` is the closest match to `desc1[i]`, `desc2[index_2]` is the second best match to `desc1[i]` and so on.